# Interleave and Deinterleave a vector into two new vectors

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

**Interleaver:** Assume we have vector `X= randi(1,N)` I would like to split the contents of `X` into two new vectors `X1`and `X2` such that the first element of `X` is the first element of `X1`, the first element of `X2` is the second element of `X`, the third element of `X` is the second element of `X1` and the fourth element of `X` is the second element of `X2`... etc till the last element of the vector `X.

I have the following idea

```
X1(1)=X(1);
X2(1)=X(2);


for i=1:length(X)
X1(i)= X(i+2);
end
for j=2:length (X)
X2(i)= X(i+2)
end
```

My question is: is my method correct? is there a better way to do it?

**Deinterleaver**
I also have the reverse problem so basically in this case I have `X1` and `X2` and would like to recover `X`, how would I efficiently recover `X`?

Comment: `X1=X(1:2:end)` `X2=X(2:2:end)` Your method wont work because on the last iteration you are asking for `X(length(X)+2)`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks. so basically there is no other way?

Comment: There are plenty of ways, yours would work if fixed.

Comment: i think your method will work fine...

Answer (score 5):

I think the terminology in this question is reversed. Interleaving would be to merge two vectors alternating their values:

```
x1 = 10:10:100;
x2 = 1:1:10;
x = [x1;x2];
x = x(:).';
```

This is the same as the one-liner:

```
x = reshape([x1;x2],[],1).';
```

Deinterleaving would be to separate the interleaved data, as already suggested by [David in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37127931/interleave-and-deinterleave-a-vector-into-two-new-vectors-matlab#comment61796469_37127931) and [Tom in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37130878/7328782):

```
y1 = x(1:2:end);
y2 = x(2:2:end);
```

but can also be done in many other ways, for example inverting the process we followed above:

```
y = reshape(x,2,[]);
y1 = y(1,:);
y2 = y(2,:);
```

To verify:

```
isequal(x1,y1)
isequal(x2,y2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was hoping, as well for some cool new one liner, but anyway, following the previous answer you can use the same indexing expression for the assignment.

```
x  = 1:20
x1 = x(1:2:end)
x2 = x(2:2:end)
y = zeros(20,1)
y(1:2:end) = x1
y(2:2:end) = x2
```

Comment: I feel I deserve some partial credit for a least provoking a much better answer.  :-) But yes, reshape is definitely the truer path.

Comment: It is true, your edit brought this question to the front page of active questions.

Comment: ... and I guess that due to the upvotes, I literally did get partial credit!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's hard to get a cleaner solution than this:

```
x  = 1:20
x1 = x(1:2:end)
x2 = x(2:2:end)
```

Comment: This is deinterlieve case, what about interlieve?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another option, you could use the [`deal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) function and some precomputed indices. This is basically the same as [the answer from Peter M](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51366250/52738), but collecting the assignments into single lines:

```
X = randi(10, [1 20]);  % Sample data
ind1 = 1:2:numel(X);    % Indices for x1
ind2 = 2:2:numel(X);    % Indices for x2

[x1, x2] = deal(X(ind1), X(ind2));  % Unweave (i.e. deinterleave)

[X(ind1), X(ind2)] = deal(x1, x2);  % Interleave
```